# Android intent data is null

Tags: android, camera, uri

I've got the following code:

```
Uri imageUri = null;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_frontpage);

this.imageView = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.pictureImageView);
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);

Intent frontPageIntent = new Intent(this, FrontPageActivity.class);
imageUri = data.getData();

frontPageIntent.putExtra(URI_PATH, imageUri.toString());
frontPageIntent.putExtra("MapPhoto", photo);

startActivity(frontPageIntent);
}
}
}
```

It tells me, that my data.getData(); is null. I've tried logging it and i get null. The code worked before, but now somehow my program crashes because of this value being null and not the uri string of the image anymore.

Can anyone spot the problem for me?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
data.getextras().get("put_here_what _you want to get");
```

Comment: Not entirely sure what to do with that?

Answer (score 0):

Check this code, It will help you :

```
private Bitmap rotatedBitmap = null;

Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
try {
    intent.putExtra("TAG_ORIENTATION", "portrait");
    intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
}
```

//OnActivity Result

```
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri selectedImageUri = null;
            if (data != null) {

                    thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                    //don't use Exif rotation here.
                    rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(thumbnail, 150, 150, true);
                    /** Convert bitmap into byte */
                    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    rotatedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100,stream);
                    //byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
                    mimEditProfileImage.setImageBitmap(rotatedBitmap);

            }       
            Toast.makeText(this, "Images Selected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }


String urlString = "";
try {
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(urlString);
    //FileBody bin = null;
    MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();

    /*if(driverImage!=null){
        bin = new FileBody(driverImage);
        reqEntity.addPart("Image", bin);
    }*/

    if(rotatedBitmap != null){
        Random generator = new Random();
        int n = 10000;
        n = generator.nextInt(n);

        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        rotatedBitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, bos);
        byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();
        ByteArrayBody bab = new ByteArrayBody(data,"dcc/"+n+".jpg");

        reqEntity.addPart("Image", bab);            
    }
post.setEntity(reqEntity);
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
            HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
            response_str = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
            if (resEntity != null) {
                //do some work
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
```

Comment: The thing is, I want my Uri to go to my next intent so i can send it to a webservice later on. But for that i need the Uri of the image so i can get a hold of it. Your code just sets the Uri to null and doesn't touch it after that, so doesn't help me much sadly.

Comment: Ok ..That means you want to post this image to server also :)

Comment: Yeah i want to post is to a server later on. But firstly i just figured i had to get a hold of the picture's uri so i can send the uri a long. Unless thats not the correct way to send a picture of course? I've done it like this before with an email, not sure how it works with webservice.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out, but all the connecting to the webservice i have in a seperate class. I can already connect to it. I just want my imageUri so i can putExtra it to my other actitivty and then that should handle it. That's what I'm trying to do with my getData method, but it gives me null.

Answer (score 0):

Just make this change in your onCreate()

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
try {

intent.putExtra("return-data", true);

startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);

} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {

e.printStackTrace();

}
```

Comment: I will try this first thing tomorrow, Thanks!